# Symfony2 with phpseclib integration

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, phpseclib

I want to integrate [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) with Symfony2

This is how we can use it with php

```
 include 'Net/SSH2.php';

 $ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
 if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
     exit('Login Failed');
 }

 echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
 echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

Any ideas how it can be done or if you know any other ways to use ssh with Symfony2 to exec commmands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your composer file:

```
require "phpseclib/phpseclib=~2.0.0"
```

Then run composer update. This should download the phpseclib library and add it to the autoloaded namespaces. You will then be able to use it in your project